# Getting error while parsing SOAP XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, soap, xml-parsing

I have following xml to parse but when my program stoped while parsing and give following error:

> [Fatal Error] :6:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

```
I have tried following java code:
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
public class ParseSoapXML {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, XmlException {

        String fileRequestInput = "C:/REQUEST_MCI_UC_41.xml";


        File xmlFileRequest = new File(fileRequestInput);
                File file = new File(fileRequestInput);

        FileInputStream fstreamRequest = new FileInputStream(xmlFileRequest);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = null;   
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;   
        Document document = null;   
        try {   
            docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();   
            document = docBuilder.parse(fstreamRequest);   
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        System.out.println("Request xml generated Parsed succesffully ");
    }
}
```

My REQUEST_MCI_UC_41.xml file contains:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeatherResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <GetWeatherResult>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <CurrentWeather>
              <Location>New Delhi / Palam, India (VIDP) 28-34N 077-07E 233M</Location>
              <Time>Nov 05, 2015 - 01:30 AM EST / 2015.11.05 0630 UTC</Time>
              <Wind>from the NW (320 degrees) at 9 MPH (8 KT):0</Wind>
              <Visibility>1 mile(s):0</Visibility>
              <SkyConditions>mostly cloudy</SkyConditions>
              <Temperature>71 F (22 C)</Temperature>
              <DewPoint>62 F (17 C)</DewPoint>
              <RelativeHumidity>73%</RelativeHumidity>
              <Pressure>29.97 in. Hg (1015 hPa)</Pressure>
              <Status>Success</Status>
            </CurrentWeather>
        </GetWeatherResult>
    </GetWeatherResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I think my program is right but may problem in xml file. Can you please help to figure out this problem

Comment: i think the problem is in this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`. It is only allowed at the top line.

Comment: @FranMontero I am getting this xml from url response then how can I fix it

Comment: First of all try to process it manually removing the problematic line